# Use Next.js project as a script tag in html file

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, next.js13, cdn

I have built a chatbot with Next.js 14 App router. Whenever you run the app a chat bubble appears at the bottom right of screen; when you click on it the chatbot appears. Now I want to use this project in a script tag which users can paste into their html files and run my code. So any users who pastes this code into their html can have a chat bubble appear on their website so they can talk to the chatbot. How can I do that?

I deployed my app to vercel. I know they have edge network. But I do not know how to generate the script tag for my code to be used in html.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.